# Can not see input view

Tags: ios, input, uitextfield, uisearchbar

In my application for iPhone I use custom input view for text field. In this input view I have  search bar. When this search bar become first responder, I can not see keyboard. Maybe, iOS can not maintenance "cascade" input views on the screen? Is any way to show multiple input views on the screen at the same time?

More details:
I have table view with text fields on each cell. Each cell configured from file (I read array with dictionaries and configure my cell, included input views of text fields). In one case I put name for the controller interface and create it dynamically. After that, I put view of this controller, as input view for text field:

```
self.pickerViewController = [self customControllerFromClassName:[self.currentFormItem controllerInputClassName]];

[_valueTextField setInputView:[self.pickerViewController view]];
[_valueTextField setInputAccessoryView:nil];
```

In this view I have search bar and I can not see input view for this one.

Comment: put your code here :)

Comment: iPatel, I have edited my question and you can see code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass UITextField, and make `YourTextfield`

and in its .m file overwrite the `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    self.background =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageBgTextField.png"];

}
```

Comment: but how borderStyle and background properties can affect to the inputView of the text field?)))

Comment: background of course make a bg for your textfield. but there you can add custom view our whatever you want